# FPDI insert html code on pdf file

Tags: php, fpdi

I use FPDI and want to insert in pdf file some html code but the method WriteHTML() is only on FPDF and not in FPDI. How can I do it?

Comment: Write the HTML with FDPF and import the generated PDF into FPDI?!

Comment: Is not that a bit too long? Instead of doing that, I know that it's best to split the html into pieces and set the contents using the setfont settext. I was hoping for something more immediate :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved by entering this script http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script42.php into fpdf_tpl.php file and I have WriteHTML() method into my FPDI class

Comment: Is it possible to show tooltip on <a href='#' title='tooltip content'>TEXT</a> on PDF?

Comment: No, the library dosent support it